# Yandex maps API. Как при клике определить код страны

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Мне нужно получить код страны в формате  ISO 3166-1 при клике на него. Кто знает помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На основе примеров из песочницы https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/regions_colors (политическая карта) и https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/regions (добавление стран или регионов) получилось вот так:

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {

  var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [56, 9],
    zoom: 1,
    type: 'yandex#map',
    controls: ['zoomControl']
  });
  map.controls.get('zoomControl').options.set({
    size: 'small'
  });
  // Зададим цвета для раскрашивания.
  // Обратите внимание, для раскраски более крупных карт нужно задавать пятый цвет.
  var colors = ['#6666F0', '#F0F075', '#FB6C3F', '#3D4C76', '#49C0B5'];

  var objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager();
  // Загрузим регионы.
  ymaps.borders.load('001', {
    lang: 'ru',
    quality: 2
  }).then(function(result) {
    // Очередь раскраски.
    var queue = [];
    // Создадим объект regions, где ключи это ISO код региона.
    var regions = result.features.reduce(function(acc, feature) {
      // Добавим ISO код региона в качестве feature.id для objectManager.
      var iso = feature.properties.iso3166;
      feature.id = iso;
      // Добавим опции региона по умолчанию.
      feature.options = {
        fillOpacity: 0.6,
        strokeColor: '#FFF',
        strokeOpacity: 0.5
      };
      acc[iso] = feature;
      return acc;
    }, {});

    // Функция, которая раскрашивает регион и добавляет всех нераскрасшенных соседей в очередь на раскраску.
    function paint(iso) {
      var allowedColors = colors.slice();
      // Получим ссылку на раскрашиваемый регион и на его соседей.
      var region = regions[iso];
      var neighbors = region.properties.neighbors;
      // Если у региона есть опция fillColor, значит мы его уже раскрасили.
      if (region.options.fillColor) {
        return;
      }
      // Если у региона есть соседи, то нужно проверить, какие цвета уже заняты.
      if (neighbors.length !== 0) {
        neighbors.forEach(function(neighbor) {
          var fillColor = regions[neighbor].options.fillColor;
          // Если регион раскрашен, то исключаем его цвет.
          if (fillColor) {
            var index = allowedColors.indexOf(fillColor);
            if (index != -1) {
              allowedColors.splice(index, 1);
            }
            // Если регион не раскрашен, то добавляем его в очередь на раскраску.
          } else if (queue.indexOf(neighbor) === -1) {
            queue.push(neighbor);
          }
        });
      }
      // Раскрасим регион в первый доступный цвет.
      region.options.fillColor = allowedColors[0];
    }

    for (var iso in regions) {
      // Если регион не раскрашен, добавим его в очередь на раскраску.
      if (!regions[iso].options.fillColor) {
        queue.push(iso);
      }
      // Раскрасим все регионы из очереди.
      while (queue.length > 0) {
        paint(queue.shift());
      }
    }
    // Добавим регионы на карту.
    result.features = [];
    for (var reg in regions) {
      result.features.push(regions[reg]);
    }
    objectManager.add(result);
    map.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
    // Подпишемся на событие клика
    map.geoObjects.events.add('click', function(e) {
      alert(e.get('objectId'));
    });
  })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Раскраска карты регионов (политическая карта)</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <!--
        Укажите свой API-ключ. Тестовый ключ НЕ БУДЕТ работать на других сайтах.
        Получить ключ можно в Кабинете разработчика: https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/keys/
    -->
  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=<ваш API-ключ>" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```